# regression analysis

Tags: regression

"A model estimated with a large no. of observations may allow one to reject null hypothesis of zero coefficients for many explanatory variables.Thus we might choose to select  a somewhat lower significance to make rejection of a null hypothesis more difficult." Provide an intuitive explanation for the above statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the "p-value problem in large samples" and s not limited to regression.  According to Cohen (1990): "a   fact   widely   understood among  statisticians:  The  null hypothesis,  taken  literally  (and  that’s  the  only  way  you  can  take  it  in  formal  hypothesis  testing),  is  always  false  in  the  real world. If  it  is  false,  even  to  a  tiny  degree,  it  must be the case that a large enough sample will produce a significant result and lead to its rejection." This is a fundamental problem with p-values.

Another statistician Chatfield  (1995)  comments,  “The  question  is  not  whether  differences  are  ‘significant’  (they nearly always are in large samples), but whether they are  interesting.  Forget  statistical significance,  what  is the practical significance of the results?” The increased power  of  large  samples  means  that  researchers  can detect smaller, subtler, and more complex effects, but relying on p-values alone can lead to claims of support for hypotheses of little or no practical significance.

Looking at practical significance is a better solution than "select a somewhat lower significance to make rejection of a null hypothesis more difficult", although the effect is similar.

I found this article interesting : Mingfeng Lin et al.: "Too Big to Fail: Large Samples and the p-Value Problem".

An analogy might be the comparison of two coins (say 2 pennies): if you have an extremely sensitive balance, able to detect differences of a few atoms, you will find that any two coins you compare are always of different weight. A statistical estimator that uses a large sample is the equivalent of the very precise balance.